# Problem with epstopdf after installing OSX El Capitan

Tags: texmaker, mac, epstopdf

After installing El Capitan I have not been able to use `epstopdf` properly. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{testeps.eps}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This gives the following error:

```
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `testeps-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.
```

What I have tried so far:

- Reinstalling Mactex
- Different combinations of `--shell-escape` and `--enable-write18`
- Reinstalling `epstopdf`

I am using TeXmaker as my editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some unsuccessful hours of searching for the right solution of the same problem, I decided to try a workaround which allows me to use epstopdf until someone developes a nice and working solution.

In my case the "epstopdf" command worked fine in the terminal, but could not be found by latex. The solution was to run the latex-editor (TexStudio) directly from the terminal (this kind of solution also helped me some time ago with compiling some Fortran-Code with Eclipse).

1. run the terminal
2. navigate to the folder of your editor, where the executable is located (e.g. cd /Applications/texstudio.app/Contents/MacOS)
3. run the editor directly from the terminal (command: ./texstudio &)

The "&" behind the name of the executable runs the editor in the background, what allows you to use the terminal-window for different things. Keep in mind, that your editor will quit, when you close the terminal-window.

Comment: Yea, this works, but it is quite an annoyance...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if any of the steps I give will help. I initially had a similar problem. But now it's working. So steps:

1. If you updated MacTex, make sure you read TeX on El Capitan (link in the MacTex page, I cannot use more than 2 links, please google MacTex yourself) and details for setting up major tex editors after el capitan update [here](https://tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf). Reinstall your tex fronts. Make sure there is no /usr/textbin. Or if you choose not to update MacTex, you can read the instructions in the pdf [here](https://tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf) and it might still work.
2. I'm using texstudio, although it claims if I installed TexLive 2015 (see step 1) first and reinstall texstudio, all paths should be fixed. I still have the epstopdf problem. So, go to texstudio preferences>build>show advanced options, under Additional Search Paths: Commands ($PATH) check your texlive version. It is likely it's still pointing to an earlier version. Since I updated mactex, so now I should have /usr/local/texlive/2015basic/bin/x86_64-darwin.

Comment: The PATH should be /Library/TeX/texbin NOT the full path to the binaries. If TeXmaker is finding (pdf)latex but can't find epstopdf you  have something misconfigured in TeXworks.

Answer (score 1):

Have the same problem. The solution above not working for me. However I found a simpler one.

So, after all the possible updates (TexShop, TexLive, etc. https://tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf), you do following:

1. Run your file with epstopdf, using TexShop. It generates the pdfs from your eps-files.
2. Now close TexShop. Run TexWorks, enjoy.

Comment: It's not really a solution, but as a quick workaround this does the job :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved following what Diode Zener with a small caveat. I write here what I did:

1. Remove epstopds package: it's not needed anymore
2. reference to figures without extensions
3. go to texstudio preferences>build>show advanced options, under Additional Search Paths: Commands ($PATH) check your texlive version. It is likely it's still pointing to an earlier version. Since I updated mactex, so now I should have /usr/local/texlive/2015/bin/x86_64-darwin.